# Whether the relevant robust optimization model can be established without using JuMPeR

Tags: julia

Since the existing JuMPeR can no longer adapt to the latest JuMP and Julia versions, and the version of the documentation is so backward that the experience of writing code is so bad that even many examples don't run smoothly, I wonder if there is an alternative package for robust optimization.

The same package has DDUS, which provides a data-driven set of uncertainties for the JuMPeR framework, but this package cannot be installed at this time.

Finally, well, if there are really no packages available, I want to know which older version of Julia can solve my problem if it can adapt to the Julia version of the JuMPeR and DDUS packages.